# What linux api I can use to measure execution time of some functions in my program?

Tags: linux

I am working on a user side application in C on linux.
What linux api I can use to measure execution time of some functions in my program?
I would like the accuracy up to nano second.

I have google it, I find example in clock clicks. I need the result in nano second.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the time.h library  to  get the begin and end times and get the difference! This is not Linux specific however!

Answer (score 0):

```
man clock_gettime
```

struct timespec is in nano second.